# Tool to generate a network diagram of docker containers in cluster

Tags: networking, diagram, docker

Is there a tool to scan network of docker containers in cluster and generate a network diagram?

I have an application running in docker container which is orchestrated with kubernetes and sometimes it is difficult to understand and see whole network image. I am looking for a tool which scans and generates a network diagram where one can see the docker virtual networks, virtual interfaces, port mappings etc.

The tool preferably runs on Linux, but Windows OS is also ok. Open source would be great, I also consider paid version.

Answer (score 2):

Some time ago I stumbled across a very same task, and I couldn't find just right tool, so I wrote my own: https://github.com/s0rg/decompose

I hope that helps.

Comment: You could improve your answer by explaining it and / or providing a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it, but I found this question in the same search as I found this, which seems to be close to what you are looking for. It doesn't look like it addresses key details like port mappings though. https://github.com/LeoVerto/docker-network-graph

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).